# Dependency Injection: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to use dependency injection (.NET Framework 4.6, ASP.NET MVC), but I am getting the error: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` If I also provide a parameterless constructor for `HomeController` then `_token` is null.

### How I properly provide this object via dependency injection?

**Owin Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IGenerateToken, GenerateTokenService>();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ueSecurityToken _token;


    public HomeController(ueSecurityToken token)
    {
        _token = token;
    }    

    public async Task<ActionResult> RunCreditCard()
    {
        var client = new UsaEPayClient();

        var request = new TransactionRequestObject
        {
            CreditCardData = new CreditCardData()
            {
                CardNumber = "4000100011112224",
                CardExpiration = "0919",
                CardCode = "123"
            }
        };
        var response = await client.runSaleAsync(_token, request);
        return View(response);
    }
}
```

**GenerateTokenService:**

```
public ueSecurityToken GenerateToken(string key, string pin)
{
    var token = new ueSecurityToken
    {
        SourceKey = key,
        ClientIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/")
    };

    var hash = new ueHash
    {
        Type = "md5",
        Seed = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };
    var input = string.Concat(token.SourceKey, hash.Seed, pin); // combine data into single string
    // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
    var md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
    var data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
    // and create a string.
    var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    foreach (var t in data)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(t.ToString("x2"));
    }
    hash.HashValue = sBuilder.ToString();
    token.PinHash = hash;
    return token;
}

public interface IGenerateToken
{
    ueSecurityToken GenerateToken(string key, string pin);
}
```

Comment: I do not know what is your specific need. But of course you can use Dependency Injection in MVC. You can refer to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/6392/dependency-injection/22128/ninject-dependency-injection#t=201609181935030109129) for *Ninject Dependency Injection*

Comment: @AdilMammadov That example is using NInject, I am referring to the Configuration/ConfigureServices functions provided in the Owin Startup Class.

Comment: (edit - apologies, misread and assumed was using ninject) Have you registered the dependency? With Ninject you need to call ( Bind<Interface>().To<Implementation>() when your application starts

Comment: Must I use a 3rd party injection provider? In .NET Core DI is included, is it not in MVC5?

Comment: I think you're injecting the wrong thing. Whatever class or interface this method belongs to - `GenerateToken` - you need to inject that. Then after injecting it, call that method to get a token. You're trying to just inject the token directly, which means you're asking DI to create a token.

Comment: Also, check the inner exception and other details to make sure you know which class it's trying to create when it says it can't find a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use DI. I prefer Simple Injector because it is simple and most cases it covers all the scenarios. For more and advancing you can use Autofac or Ninject.

But your method in controller it not hit by the DI. They set the constructors for the classes. So your DI has no use in this case.

Comment: I see! I need to place it on the Constructor of my Controller, not on one of the Actions!

Comment: exactly! Just for curiousity.. Why would you want a token in a constructor?

Comment: Well, that broke it :(, updated question. It's for a payment processing platform, and every Action of the Controller uses the token, so I would like to generate it and store it once, then reference it when I need it within Controllers that need it.

Comment: And for even more advanced cases you can use Structuremap... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a comment...
the DI can't resolve this, and thus you get an error :)
What does GenerateToken do? Is this a static function/class? You might want to create an interface:

```
public interface IGenerateToken
{ 
    string GenerateToken();
}
```

and a class:

```
public class GenerateTokenService : IGenerateToken
{
  //your logic
}
```

then in your DI you can add a singleton for creating a token:

```
services.AddSingleton<IGenerateToken, GenerateTokenService >();
```

And in your constructur:

```
private readonly IGenerateToken _token;

public HomeController(IGenerateToken token)
{
    _token = token;
}
```

This makes testing also better :)

Try it!

Comment: That is much better! Thanks, unfortunately it still threw the same error:
 `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: @AdamReed did you resolve this?  Getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

With **ASP.NET 6** you might also get this error with a Blazor/Razor component. The component needs the empty constructor.

To solve this, you can use a property and mark it with `Inject` like this:

```
[Inject]
protected IDataAccess DataRepository { get; set; }
```

More info: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-a-service-in-a-component)

Comment: This question is specifically for asp.net, not ASP.NET Core. Therefore, this answer isn't applicable and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem, after digging out found the article above.
I had to modify the method BuildUnityContainer to register my service.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection