# Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor error.Error for sometimes

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, autofac

In App_Start

```
IContainer container = SetupDependencyInjection();
```

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);`

and

```
 private IContainer SetupDependencyInjection()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        return container;
    }
```

This is working good but sometimes it shows error 
`Error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ControllerName'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

i am new to Web Api. Please help me.

Comment: I would assume that this is a result of your IoC container not being able to resolve dependencies for `ControllerName`, normally due to lack of registration of the resolved types. Make sure parameters `ControllerName` ctor expects are registered in your IoC container.

Comment: Have you searched for an answer using the error message? This is a really common question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927507/none-of-the-constructors-found-with-autofac-core-activators-reflection-defaultc)

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38927507/8116 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/39561779/8116 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/40005815/8116 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/40341738/8116